# USB 2.0 circuit

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I am designing and using a USB 2.0 (High-Speed) specification circuit.

The circuit is shown as below.

[image: USB data line invalid capacitors]

Sometimes CPU cannot recognize the USB stick (USB 2.0 High speed).

At first, I changed the resistors from 0 ohms to 27 ohms.
However, CPU still could not recognize the USB stick.

So, when I removed both the 22 pF capacitors (open status), CPU can recognize the USB stick very well.

What is the problem?

I know the role of 22pF capacitors with the series resistors is to remove ringing of the signal causing the EMI.

But when I removed the capacitors, the problem was solved (with still 0 ohms series remaining). Indeed, I can not understand the difference between the existence of capacitors of open circuit (removing capacitor) on the USB data differential signal by using an oscilloscope.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the signal waveforms in the data lines? Please provide some results.

Comment: Perhaps the one of the capacitors you removed was shorted out? Just a guess. There isn't much any of us can do but guess with the information you have provided. Things like PCB layouts, photographs, scope waveforms would all be useful.

Comment: 22pF seems quite high. Where did you get that figure from?

Comment: Section 7.1.6.2 of USB 2.0 spec has the details you need. You need to be very careful with termination if you want any sort of reliability in the field. As you can see from the spec, it's a bit more complicated than just adding a cap and resistor.

Comment: USB 2 operates at 480 Mbit/s maximum. Work out the effect 22pF capacitors have at that sort of frequency and you'll see why nobody puts them in their designs.

Comment: @Finbarr 
Then the impedance@240MHz of 22pF is approximately 30.15ohm.
So, if i change from the 22pF to 14.74pF(@240MHz, 45ohm), it will be ok?
because, in the USB2.0 Spec. 7.1.6.2, the diff termination resistance is recommended as 80ohm < Z < 100ohm.
is that right?

Comment: Why have you worked it out at 240 MHz?

Comment: @Finbarr although the communication speed is 480Mbps, the clock cycle is 240MHz with considering clock cycle. Is that right??

Comment: @Finbarr. I think 240Mhz sqare wave and 480Mbps have same speed pattern.

Comment: A square wave has a LOT of harmonics. Although the signal on a USB cable isn't perfectly square, you would need to go a lot lower with your capacitor. But refer to the proper spec anyway, this isn't the way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With 22 pF to ground, the link won't work. Having 22 pF is a brutal violation of USB 2.0 signal requirements.

When you loaded the data bus with such huge caps, the HS (480 mbps, 240 MHz) signals are severely degraded, below borderline of HS communication. Yet the initial speed negotiation (chirping sequence), which occurs on 10 kHz rate (50 us pulses), passes just fine. So the host receives a valid HS handshake and believes that the device is HS-device, and therefore starts the communication at HS rate. But your 22 pF hammers the HS signal, and all HS protocol fails, or is very-very unreliable. That's where your design fails.

Apparently you have mixed up old USB 1.1 (FS) recommendations with HS fully-terminated transmission line requirements. Urgently remove all your caps (and resistors) from USB data lines.

Comment: Is the role of cap as EMI suppression valid only for USB1.1??  Not 2.0?

Comment: The "EMI suppression cap" is a blast of deep past, when full-speed drivers didn't have any means to control the signal edge rising time, so the lines would ring like hell without R and C. Not anymore, all USB 2.0 HS-compliant drivers must have edge control, otherwise, with the absence of caps and resistors for HS mode, they would not pass USB silicon certification. So caps can't be used, and there is no needs for any caps, since the edges are already bandwidth limited.

Comment: Then, are 15kohm resistor(pull-down) also not needed?!  Why could this pull down resistor not work as pull down in this design???

Comment: Usually the 15k pull downs are also incorporated in PHY circuitry for downstream-facing ports. What kind of "CPU" are you using?

Comment: Samsung CPU based on ARM 8 or 9!!

Comment: In this CPU, the usb 2.0 HS Host driver is embeded!